# Command to display virtualbox vm network information

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am having two VMs VM1 and VM2 i want to attach same network of VM1 to VM2.
For that i want to displaying virtualbox VM network information and parse the output.
And then attach same network to VM2.
Can anybody tell me the command to display VM network information.
Is there any other easy solution for my problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi i found Command to display Virtualbox network info

```
vboxmanage showvminfo <VM Name> |grep "NIC"
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows detailed NIC information for each VM of VirtualBox.

```
VBoxManage list vms |perl -ne 'print "echo \"NIC $1\"; VBoxManage showvminfo $2\n" if(/\"(.*)\" \{(.*)\}/o);' | sh | egrep "^NIC"
```

usefull to find which VM use which NIC and network id too.

If you like, use `-x` option to `sh` too.